# How to serve a mobile version of website to phones

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have searched but don't find what I am looking for here on the forum.  I have a standard HTML (not wordpress) website.  It displays great on desktop and ipad.  I built a mobile version that is very scaled down with just basic information using jquery mobile.
The question is, how do I serve the mobile files to only phones?  What code can I use to tell the phone to use the jquery mobile files or url instead of the normal desktop files? I also added a "view full site" button on the jquery mobile version of the site.  How do I get the phones to display the full site if "view full site" is selected and not go back to the mobile version once selected?  I see this done on many sites but have not been able to figure it out.  Thanks for any help! Mike

**This is my main site at mikeschaler.com**

```
// will allow to use sessions
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['mobile_detect'])) {
    require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect;

    if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
        header('Location: mobile.mikeschaler.com');    
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />


<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/MESfavicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="/MESfavicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<title>Mike Schaler Media Services</title>

<style type="text/css"></style>

<link href="mikeSiteRedesign.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-19130075-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

</head>
```

**This is the mobile site I am trying to serve to mobile users at mobile.mikeschaler.com:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Precison Garage Door</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/Precision-Garage-Door.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>

session_start();
$_SESSION['mobile_detect'] = 0;
header('Location: mikeschaler.com/index.html');

    </head>
```

Is this what you are looking for?  Thanks!

Ok, I deleted the code from the mobile.mikeschaler.com site. 
I created a php file with the "// will allow to use sessions session start..." code.
On the mikeschaler.com site I inserted at the top of the code   Do I have all of this correct? Mike

Full site code looks like this now:

```
<?php 
mobileRedirect.php 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: You have to put the PHP into a <?php YOUR CODE ?> and save the file as .php. Also, retire the PHP code from your mobile website. We'r gonna do that step by step.

Comment: Hoping you saw my response above. Thanks for hanging in there with me on this! Mike

Comment: It should be correct if you didn't forget to put the code into a <?php ?>

Comment: Yes, I missed that.  Changed and re-uploaded the php file now.

Comment: But do I have this right on the full site to call the php redirect file?  <?php mobileRedirect.php ?> Not sure the syntax to execute the php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// will allow to use sessions
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['mobile_detect'])) {
    require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect;

    if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
        header('Location: mobile.mikeschaler.com');    
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Here's the code you have to put instead of yours.

And then the code in mobile.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['mobile_detect'] = 0;
header('Location: /'); // "/" to redirect to the root path
?>
```

Comment: Hmm. When I added it I see part of the code at the top of the page mikeschaler.com

Comment: You have to save it as a .php

Comment: Oh, do you mean my index file?  So I save my index.html file as index.php?  Never crossed my mind!  So then I assume I delete my index.html file and upload the index.php file.  Will the server know to use the php instead?  New territory for me!  Thanks

Comment: This is getting interesting!  Ok, the index.php page (home page) looks good now.  When I go to the mobile.mikeschaler.com url on my desktop it looks as expected. You can guess what I'm typing next... on my phone when I go to the mikeschaler.com url it redirects to mobile.mikeschaler.com but then says 404 error page not found. I have to admit this is getting pretty exciting.

Comment: You have to set the full url in the header location : http:// because without it, it will consider your url is a page or a folder.

Comment: Yep, that worked!  Rookie mistake on my part. So now it loads the correct mobile site.  When I tap the "visit full site" button it returns to the mobile.mikeschaler.com.  I have the URL for the button: http://mikeschaler.com/?mobileoverride=true.

Comment: I suggest you to change the URL to mikeschaler.com/mobile.php for example, and then create a mobile.php file where you'll put the second code (I just edited this post with the code).

Comment: So the code you edited above goes at the top of the html code for the mobile site like the index.php file we made for the full site and gets saved and uploaded as mobile.php?

Comment: No your mobile site has a button "Go to Full website", this button redirects to mobile.php which has this code. The header('Location: /'); will then redirect to the full website.

Comment: Awesome!  It works now! I wonder if I can repeat this for another site ?  I think so.  So after tapping the "visit full site" button and going to the homepage on the full site, It seems I can't get back to the mobile site.  Any thoughts on that?  Only way I can get there is by using the back button but after choosing full site how could I go back to the mobile site on subsequent visits?  I found if I power down my phone or restart it I can get back to the mobile site.

Comment: It's just a session. If the user closes the tab, then he will go back to the mobile version. You can also put a link to the mobile version at the bottom of your website so the user can get back to it.

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you so much!  I really appreciate all your patience with my inexperience.  I can't wait to show the functionality of this to my boss.  He will be very pleased.  Know that you have helped an old guy trying to find his way in a new field after 30+ years in another line of work.  Mike

Comment: No problem. Totally understand. Finding time to learn those things if you don't really use them can be hard. Don't forget to indicate the answer as approved ;).

Comment: I am also a newbie to this forum on stackoverflow.  I checked both items to the left.  I hope that is where I needed to approve the answers.  If not let me know and I'll do whatever I need to give you excellent feedback! Mike

Comment: @Code196 Just checked everything on my iPad and it is serving up the mobile version of the site first.  I expected that as I remember seeing some settings as I looked thru the code.  Is there some setting to change so tablets get served the full site instead of the phone version? Thanks!

Comment: @MikeS instead of `if( $detect->isMobile() {`, write `if( $detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet() ){` it will exclude tablets from redirection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some PHP scripts to detect the mobile version like: http://mobiledetect.net/

Then, for the "Full website" button, send the user to a: fullwebsite.php. The page will set a session which indicates that it has to not detect the mobile version.

```
// will allow to use sessions
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['mobile_detect'])) {
    require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect;

    if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
        header('Location: your_url.html');
    }
}
```

the page which sets the session:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['mobile_detect'] = 0;
header('Location: full_website.html');
```

Comment: Thanks Codel96, I don't really know much about php except that I can use HTML within a PHP file.  I looked at the mobiledetect.net site and there is some great info there.  How would I implement the php script to only serve the mobile version to phones?  Would I simply insert it into the header of my site?  Then for the "view full site" where would that code go?  I can email a link to what I am working on if you would like to see it.  Thanks for your help!  Mike

Comment: The first code I gave must go to the top of your file, before the HTML then you can do a redirection (I edited my code). Just download the Mobile_detect.php, put it on your server at the same path of your file and put that code into the file which must redirect.

Comment: Struggling here... I copied the first code and added my mobile site url. Here is the code I used:                                        // will allow to use sessions
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['mobile_detect'])) {
    require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect;

    if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
        header('mobile.mikeschaler.com/index.html');
    }
}     I put it above the closing </head> tag.  I downloaded the mobile_detect.php file but there are many files and folders in the download.  Not sure if I need to upload the whole folder or just one file.

Comment: There are 2 php files with the name Mobile Detect... MobileDetect.php and Mobile_Detect.php I assume I use the 2nd one as it is in the script.  So finally, the last code: session_start();
$_SESSION['mobile_detect'] = 0;
header('Location: mikeschaler.com/index.html'); would go on the mobile site above the closing </head? tag?  Thanks for your patience and help!  Mike

Comment: The first bit of code gets injected into the header of my site: mikeschaler.com Not sure why except maybe because the 2nd if statement says header('mobile.mikeschaler.com/index.html');

Comment: The code I gave you should go at the top of the page. It is PHP, not HTML so even before the doctype.

Comment: Thanks, I put it above the doctype and it still displays at the top of the home page: mikeschaler.com  Mike

Comment: You have to write header('Location: url'); not just "url".

Comment: Hmmm, seems to be the same result.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you are asking for?  Do you mean my original question or after your first response? I can post any code from the site you like just not sure what you need to see.

Comment: This is my full site: mikeschaler.com I built a mobile site for testing to show a prospective client at mobile.mikeschaler.com It is obviously not a scaled down version of my full site but a device I built to learn how to deliver a mobile version of a site. So my full site code is:

Comment: // will allow to use sessions
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['mobile_detect'])) {
    require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect;

    if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
        header('Location: mobile.mikeschaler.com');    
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Comment: Mobile site code is: <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Precison</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/Precision-Garage-Door.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.0.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>

session_start();
$_SESSION['mobile_detect'] = 0;
header('Location: mikeschaler.com/index.html');

 </head>

Comment: I asked you to edit your first question... I won't do anything on a code like this. Please indent and edit.

Comment: I have a standard HTML website mikeschaler.com It displays great on desktop and ipad. I built a mobile version that is very scaled down to test with just basic information using jquery mobile at mobile.mikeschaler.com How do I serve the mobile files to only phones? What code can I use to tell the phone to use the jquery mobile files or url instead of the normal desktop files? I also added a "view full site" button on the jquery mobile version of the site that links to mikeschaler.com How do I get phones to display full site if "view full site" is selected and not go back to mobile version?

Comment: Just a little question, do you know the meaning of "editing"? Edit means you have to change the message of your first post by pasting your code.

Comment: My apologies, I'm feeling pretty stupid right now. I guess not.  When you asked "Could you edit your first post with your code" I really didn't understand what you were asking for. I apparently still don't understand what you are looking for. I am relatively inexperienced with all of this. Only been at it for 4 years and don't know php at all. I really appreciate your patience and help. Can you help me understand better what you are looking for? Mike

Comment: Sorry I now see that my post wasn't really clear. What I want is you to edit your FIRST message by clicking the "edit" button below the "tags" and then paste your new code ;).

Comment: Ok, I hope what I added at the top of the page is what you need. Mike

Comment: I answered in the comments of the first message.

Comment: Hi @Code196, Are you available anytime today or this evening to take a look at the modifications I have made today? I really appreciate your help! Mike

Comment: <?php 
mobileRedirect.php 
?>

what is that ?

Comment: That is the php file I created using the session start php code.  I uploaded this file to the root of my full site.